# Scheduling a chess tournament

Tags: code-golf

#### Introduction

Right now I'm participating a chess tournament. I got inspired by the tournament schedule. Right now, I'm in a competition with three other players. That means with the four of us, we are playing 3 rounds. The schedule goes as following:

```
Round 1: 1-4 3-2
Round 2: 3-4 2-1
Round 3: 1-3 4-2
```

This is also known as **Round Robin**. Also, this is a **valid** schedule. We say that a schedule is valid, when it satisfies the following conditions:

- Every player plays **once** against another player.
- `1-2` means that player `1` has **white**. Every player has or (*N / 2 - 0.5*) or (*N / 2 + 0.5*) times white, with *N* being the amount of rounds.

For example, in the above example, there are **3** rounds. So N = 3. As you can see, **the amount of rounds equals the amount of players - 1**. A player has either

- *N / 2 - 0.5* = **1** time white, or
- *N / 2 + 0.5* = **2** times white.

In the above example:

- player `1` has **2 times** white,
- player `2` has **1 time** white,
- player `3` has **2 times** white,
- player `4` has **1 time** white.

#### The task

Given an **even** integer > 1 representing the amount of players in the competition, output the tournament schedule.

#### Test cases:

Input = 4, that means N = 3

```
Input:     Output:
4          1-4 3-2
           3-4 2-1
           1-3 4-2
```

Input = 10, that means N = 9

```
Input:     Output:
10         1-10  2-9  3-8  4-7  5-6
           10-6  7-5  8-4  9-3  1-2
           2-10  3-1  4-9  5-8  6-7
           10-7  8-6  9-5  1-4  2-3
           3-10  4-2  5-1  6-9  7-8
           10-8  9-7  1-6  2-5  3-4
           4-10  5-3  6-2  7-1  8-9
           10-9  1-8  2-7  3-6  4-5
           5-10  6-4  7-3  8-2  9-1
```

Input = 12, that means N = 11

```
Input:     Output:
12         1-14    2-13   3-12   4-11   5-10   6-9    7-8
           14-8    9-7    10-6   11-5   12-4   13-3   1-2
           2-14    3-1    4-13   5-12   6-11   7-10   8-9
           14-9    10-8   11-7   12-6   13-5   1-4    2-3
           3-14    4-2    5-1    6-13   7-12   8-11   9-10
           14-10   11-9   12-8   13-7   1-6    2-5    3-4
           4-14    5-3    6-2    7-1    8-13   9-12   10-11
           14-11   12-10  13-9   1-8    2-7    3-6    4-5
           5-14    6-4    7-3    8-2    9-1    10-13  11-12
           14-12   13-11  1-10   2-9    3-8    4-7    5-6
           6-14    7-5    8-4    9-3    10-2   11-1   12-13
           14-13   1-12   2-11   3-10   4-9    5-8    6-7
           7-14    8-6    9-5    10-4   11-3   12-2   13-1
```

Of course, the extra whitespaces I used between the numbers is **optional** but not necessary. You may output it in any form you like, as long as it's readable.

**Note:** The above examples aren't just the *only* valid outputs. There certainly are more valid outputs.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!

Comment: I think that validity is underspecified. In particular, shouldn't it require that the number of rounds is one less than the number of players?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, I forgot to mention that. I have edited it in the question

Comment: Do players have to be numbered 1 to N, or can they be numbered 0 to N-1?

Comment: @steveverrill Whatever fits best for you.

Comment: Do you have to separate the rounds in the outputs or is `1-4 3-2 3-4 2-1 1-3 4-2` for `n=4` a valid output?

Comment: @randomra Rounds should be separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Python 2, <s>200</s> 186 Bytes

---

```py
n=input()
t=range(2,n+1)
for k in t:
 s=[1]+t
 c=[[s[x],s[-x-1]] for x in range(n/2)]
 if k%2:c[0].reverse()
 t=t[-1:]+t[:-1]
 print"\t".join(["-".join([str(y) for y in x]) for x in c])
```

---

Example output:

```
$ python chess.py
4
1-4     2-3
3-1     4-2
1-2     3-4

$ python chess.py
10
1-10    2-9     3-8     4-7     5-6
9-1     10-8    2-7     3-6     4-5
1-8     9-7     10-6    2-5     3-4
7-1     8-6     9-5     10-4    2-3
1-6     7-5     8-4     9-3     10-2
5-1     6-4     7-3     8-2     9-10
1-4     5-3     6-2     7-10    8-9
3-1     4-2     5-10    6-9     7-8
1-2     3-10    4-9     5-8     6-7

$ python chess.py
14
1-14    2-13    3-12    4-11    5-10    6-9     7-8
13-1    14-12   2-11    3-10    4-9     5-8     6-7
1-12    13-11   14-10   2-9     3-8     4-7     5-6
11-1    12-10   13-9    14-8    2-7     3-6     4-5
1-10    11-9    12-8    13-7    14-6    2-5     3-4
9-1     10-8    11-7    12-6    13-5    14-4    2-3
1-8     9-7     10-6    11-5    12-4    13-3    14-2
7-1     8-6     9-5     10-4    11-3    12-2    13-14
1-6     7-5     8-4     9-3     10-2    11-14   12-13
5-1     6-4     7-3     8-2     9-14    10-13   11-12
1-4     5-3     6-2     7-14    8-13    9-12    10-11
3-1     4-2     5-14    6-13    7-12    8-11    9-10
1-2     3-14    4-13    5-12    6-11    7-10    8-9
```

---

Or **135 Bytes**, by using a less pretty (but still readable) output:

```
...
print c
```

Which produces something like:

```
$ python chess.py
4
[[1, 4], [2, 3]]
[[3, 1], [4, 2]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: The less pretty answer is also a valid submission. So this is 135 bytes :)

Comment: I'd upvote you if you added a human explanation of your algorithm.